# How to sort rows in a text file in Perl?

Tags: perl, scripting, sorting

I have a couple of text files (`A.txt` and `B.txt`) which look like this (might have ~10000 rows each)

```
processa,id1=123,id2=5321
processa,id1=432,id2=3721
processa,id1=3,id2=521
processb,id1=9822,id2=521
processa,id1=213,id2=1
processc,id1=822,id2=521
```

I need to check if every row in file `A.txt` is present in `B.txt` as well (`B.txt` might have more too, that is okay).

The thing is that rows can be in any order in the two files, so I am thinking I will sort them in some particular order in both the files in `O(nlogn)` and then match each line in `A.txt` to the next lines in `B.txt` in `O(n)`. I could implement a hash, but the files are big and this comparison happens only once after which these files are regenerated, so I don't think that is a good idea.

**What is the best way to sort the files in Perl?** Any ordering would do, it just needs to be *some* ordering.

For example, in dictionary ordering, this would be

```
processa,id1=123,id2=5321
processa,id1=213,id2=1
processa,id1=3,id2=521
processa,id1=432,id2=3721
processb,id1=9822,id2=521
processc,id1=822,id2=521
```

As I mentioned before, any ordering would be just as fine, as long as Perl is fast in doing it.

I want to do it from within Perl code, after opening the file like so

```
open (FH, "<A.txt");
```

Any comments, ideas etc would be helpful.

Comment: If you're doing 10,000 rows, and you're planning on using this more than once -- at the least I'd be using SQL Lite.

Comment: A hash and a sort both require you to load the entire `A.txt` file into memory. Why do you think sorting is better than using a hash?

Comment: @mobrule: I thought that Perl might have some intelligent way of sorting it, given that it is a language that is built for dealing with text. Some way that is better than implementing a hash myself. From the answers below, it seems that hashing is after all a good idea!

Comment: as long as you can handle it in memory you're good to go.

Answer (score 5):

To sort the file in your script, you will still have to load the entire thing into memory.  If you're doing that, I'm not sure what's the advantage of sorting it vs just loading it into a hash?

Something like this would work:

```
my %seen;
open(A, "<A.txt") or die "Can't read A: $!";
while (<A>) {
    $seen{$_}=1;
}
close A;

open(B, "<B.txt") or die "Can't read B: $!";
while(<B>) {
  delete $seen{$_};
}
close B;

print "Lines found in A, missing in B:\n";
join "\n", keys %seen;
```

Comment: It isn't necessary to load the entire file into memory at once in order to sort it.  That's why the merge sort was invented.  But if you have enough memory, this is a good approach.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way to do it. The idea is to create a flexible data structure that allows you to answer many kinds of questions easily with `grep`.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my ($fileA, $fileB) = @ARGV;

# Load all lines: $h{LINE}{FILE_NAME} = TALLY
my %h;
$h{$_}{$ARGV} ++ while <>;

# Do whatever you need.
my @all_lines = keys %h;
my @in_both   = grep {     keys %{$h{$_}} == 2       } keys %h;
my @in_A      = grep {     exists $h{$_}{$fileA}     } keys %h;
my @only_in_A = grep { not exists $h{$_}{$fileB}     } @in_A;
my @in_A_mult = grep {            $h{$_}{$fileA} > 1 } @in_A;
```

Comment: What if a given line occurs twice in one file but zero in the other?

Comment: @HerbN It works fine. The N of keys in `%{$h{LINE}}` tells you how many files a particular LINE occurred in. And the tallies are file-specific: each tally tells you the N of times a particular LINE occurred within a particular FILE.

Answer (score 0):

well, i routinely parse very large (600MB) daily Apache log files with Perl, and to store the information i use a hash.  I also go through about 30 of these files, in one script instance, using the same hash.  its not a big deal assuming you have enough RAM.

Answer (score 0):

May I ask why you must do this in native Perl? If the cost of calling a system call or 3 is not an issue (e.g. you do this infrequently and not in a tight loop), why not simply do:

```
my $cmd = "sort $file1 > $file1.sorted";
$cmd .= "; sort $file2 > $file2.sorted";
$cmd .= "; comm -23 $file1.sorted $file2.sorted |wc -l";
my $count = `$cmd`;
$count =~ s/\s+//g;
if ($count != 0) {
    print "Stuff in A exists that aren't in B\n";
}
```

Please note that `comm` parameter might be different, depending on what exactly you want.

Comment: This comparison is only a small part of what my Perl script does. These files are generated, compared and processed. As to why I am doing the whole thing in Perl, I need things to be portable, and work on a variety of environments, not just Unix.

Comment: Well, both of these (sort and comm and probably wc) should be available on Windows as well,  but yeah, this is obviously less portable, you're right. It is however much more optimized for large files. If you need pure Perl portability, the hash solution is your ticket.

Answer (score 0):

Test if `A.txt` is a subset of `B.txt`

```
open FILE.B, "B.txt";
open FILE.A, "A.txt";

my %bFile;

while(<FILE.B>) {
   ($process, $id1, $id2) = split /,/;
   $bFile{$process}{$id1}{$id2}++;
}

$missingRows = 0;

while(<FILE.A>) {
   $missingRows++ unless $bFile{$process}{$id1}{$id2};
   # If we've seen a given entry already don't add it
   next if $missingRows; # One miss means they aren't all verified
}

$is_Atxt_Subset_Btxt = $missingRows?FALSE:TRUE;
```

That will give you a test for all rows in A being in B with only reading in all of B and then testing each member of the array while reading A.

Comment: No, I do not add or delete any information to the files. I just rearrange what is already there. The idea is to check whether `A.txt` is a subset of `B.txt` or not.

Comment: @Lazer: Updated to do just that.

Answer (score 0):

As usual, [CPAN](http://search.cpan.org/) has an answer for this.  Either [Sort::External](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Sort::External) or [File::Sort](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File::Sort) looks like it would work.  I've never had occasion to try either, so I don't know which would be better for you.

Another possibility would be to use [AnyDBM_File](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?AnyDBM_File) to create a disk-based hash that can exceed available memory.  Without trying it, I couldn't say whether using a DBM file would be faster or slower than the sort, but the code would probably be simpler.